# Getting nearest places details by list from Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to get nearest places details from Google Map.

**This is my code**: http://jsfiddle.net/sankars/WZ7Y8/8/

For example: If I click hotel I want all hotels name with address by list nearest or with in 10KM from places. If I click restaurant I want all restaurants name with address by list nearest or with in 10KM from places.How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Places library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html).  It won't give you ALL hotels, but up to 20 for any one type.